# How to show the corresponding git commands in Sourcetree?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

When I make a change in Sourcetree, a dialog box appears and I can click "Show Full Output" to see the corresponding command-line git commands. But when the command works quickly you can miss clicking show full output. Is there somewhere I can see a history of commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Mac, in the menu bar select `View > Show Command History` to show all run git commands.

Answer (score 6):

At SourceTree for Windows, Tools --> Process Viewer...